# RestEasy: @PathParam returns first word if string has spaces

Tags: java, jboss, jax-rs, resteasy, wildfly

My `API` endpoint looks like

```
@GET
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("groups/{groupName}")
public Response getCategoriesByGroupName(@PathParam("groupName") @Nonnull final String groupName) {
    return Response.ok(getCategoryTO().getCategoriesByGroupName(categoryManager, groupName)).build();
}
```

When I try to hit the endpoint as

```
curl -H"Content-Type: application/json" -H"BEARER:792345452:78f7f8a4-a8c9-454a-93a8-6633a1076781:169000000"  "https://myapp.com/rest/categories/groups/Utilities"
```

I get the correct `JSON` back, meaning `groupName` is correctly substituted with `Utilities`

But when I do

```
curl -H"Content-Type: application/json" -H"BEARER:792345452:78f7f8a4-a8c9-454a-93a8-6633a1076781:169000000"  "https://myapp.com/rest/categories/groups/Food & Drink"
```

I see server error as

```
Caused by: javax.ejb.EJBException: javax.persistence.NoResultException: no categories exists with groupName: Food
```

The problem is that `groupName` was substituted as `Food` instead of `Food & Drink`

I tried with other `groupName`s and realized that whenever my `groupName` has spaces, only the first word is substituted as `groupName`

How can I fix this issue so that entire string passed in `URL` becomes `groupName`?

My server is deployed on `Wildfly 8`

Comment: `&` is a special character. You need to encode it.

Comment: Can you guide me how to do that?

Comment: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

Comment: use `URLEncoder.encode(stringToEncode, "UTF-8");`

Answer (score 0):

That has nothing to do with my endpoint.

As mentioned by @Sotirios, I needed to encode my URL before sending it to server.

When I did that thing started to work

```
curl -H"Content-Type: application/json" -H"BEARER: 792345452:78f7f8a4-a8c9-454a-93a8-6633a1076781:169000000"  "https://myapp.com/rest/categories/groups/Food%20%26%20Drink"

[{"id":"9b1e97f2-ac7d-4caf-85fc-476cd97dd6cb","name":"Alcohol & Bars","groupName":"Food & Drink"}]
```

Comment: URL encoding is a common practice.  Not only do you need to replace & but also ` ` with `%20`